# R: import satellite image for specific region

Tags: r, maps, spatial, raster

Based on simulation data I have created raster file that indicates hazard, aka hazard map:

```
      library(raster)
  rockfall_intensity <- raster (xmn = 696583.6, xmx = 696799.6, ymn = 167579.6, ymx = 167789.6, res = 2,
                                  crs = "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")

  # average kinetic energy per raster cell
  rockfall_intensity <- rasterize(trjct[, c('x', 'y')], rockfall_intensity, trjct$Etot, fun = mean)
  plot(rockfall_intensity, col=brewer.pal(9,"YlOrRd"))
```

[image]

I want to download satelite image for this region (and pin the raster on top). I have looked into the `get_map` function

```
  ??get_map
  mapImageData3 <- get_map(location = c(lon = -7.439583333333333, lat = 46.95240555555556),
                           color = "color",
                           source = "google",
                           maptype = "roadmap",
                           zoom = 16)

  ggmap(mapImageData3,
        extent = "device",
        ylab = "Latitude",
        xlab = "Longitude")

Theme element panel.border missing
Error in if (theme$panel.ontop) { : argument is of length zero
In addition: Warning message:
`panel.margin` is deprecated. Please use `panel.spacing` property instead
```

How can I fix the error ?
Is this there a better way to do this?

I am hoping to get an hazad map, something like: 
[image]

Comment: can you clarify your error? What do you mean when you say "How can I fix the error"? What are you getting.?

Comment: @DanHall, sorry - just added clarification

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems here:

1. Your location is in the middle of the ocean. You're selecting roadmap, at a very high zoom. So you will see nothing but blue.
2. Use maptype = "satellite" if you want the kind of map you're showing in the photo above, and a smaller zoom.
3. If you want to actually see the labels (**and not get the warning**), select a different value for extent.

For example:

```
mapImageData3 <- get_map(location = c(lon = -7.43958, lat = 46.95241),
                         color = "color", source = "google", 
                         maptype = "satellite", zoom = 7)
ggmap(mapImageData3, extent = "normal", ylab = "Lattitude", 
      xlab = "Longitude")
```